# Ipsec tunnel with solaris10..what I miss?

Tags: solaris, vpn, ipsec

I want to create a two Solaris10 tunnel encrypted with ipsec.Configuration is simple: 2 solaris10 nodes,lan not encrypted,tunnel encrypted.
Lan is e1000g0 and tunnel is ip.tun0
Ip "clear" for node1 is 192.168.0.21 
Ip "clear" for node2 is 192.168.0.199
I do this procedure

a)Enabled ipv4 forwaring and routing in both nodes

```
routeadm -u -e ipv4-routing
routeadm -u -e ipv4-forwarding
```

b)Edited /etc/inet/ike/config on both nodes

```
p1_xform
  { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha encr_alg 3des }
p2_pfs 2
```

c)Edited  /etc/inet/secret/ike.preshared on both nodes,of course with reverse local/remote

```
{ localidtype IP
    localid 192.168.0.21
    remoteidtype IP
    remoteid 192.168.0.119
  }
```

d)Enable IKE on both nodes,svcs confirm is working

```
svcadm enable ike
svcs ike
```

e)Edit file /etc/inet/ipsecinit.conf

```
# LAN traffic to and from this host can bypass IPsec.
{laddr 192.168.0.0 dir both} bypass {}

# WAN traffic uses ESP with AES and SHA-1.
{tunnel ip.tun0 negotiate tunnel}
 ipsec {encr_algs aes encr_auth_algs sha1 sa shared}
```

f)Refresh..

```
svcadm refresh ipsec/policy
```

g)Seems all ok,so I create the tunnel

```
svcs -a|grep -i ipsec
disabled        9:35:34 svc:/network/ipsec/manual-key:default
online          9:35:53 svc:/network/ipsec/ipsecalgs:default
online          9:35:53 svc:/network/ipsec/ike:default
online          9:54:38 svc:/network/ipsec/policy:default
```

On HostA

```
ifconfig ip.tun0 plumb
ifconfig ip.tun0 192.168.192.24 192.168.192.40 tsrc 192.168.0.21 tdst 192.168.0.199 router up
```

On HostB

```
ifconfig ip.tun0 plumb
ifconfig ip.tun0 192.168.192.40 192.168.192.24 tsrc 192.168.0.199 tdst 192.168.0.21 router up
```

Seems all OK but..don't work.

HostA can ping HostB

```
ping 192.168.0.199
192.168.0.199 is alive
```

HostB can ping HostA

```
ping 192.168.0.2
192.168.0.2 is alive
```

But If I ping the tunnel...

From HostA to HostB

```
ping -s 192.168.192.40
PING 192.168.192.40: 56 data bytes
----192.168.192.40 PING Statistics----
25 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

From HostB to HostA

```
ping -s 192.168.192.24
PING 192.168.192.24: 56 data bytes
----192.168.192.24 PING Statistics----
25 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

on hostA netstat -rn said

```
netstat -rn
Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              192.168.0.1          UG        1          1           
192.168.0.0          192.168.0.21         U         1          3 e1000g0   
192.168.192.40       192.168.192.24       UH        1          0 ip.tun0   
224.0.0.0            192.168.0.21         U         1          0 e1000g0   
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        1         48 lo0
```

On HostB netstat -rn said

```
Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              192.168.0.1          UG        1          2 e1000g0   
192.168.0.0          192.168.0.199        U         1          7 e1000g0   
192.168.192.24       192.168.192.40       UH        1          1 ip.tun0   
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        3        122 lo0
```

What I miss?Firewall is disabled on both nodes.

Comment: What is the result of `netstat -rn`?

Comment: I will add now to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
The error was in syntax of many conf. files
First the file

```
/etc/inet/ike.preshared
```

must be like this,the ip 
to use must be the ip of the tunnel not the ip 
of "main" interface.

```
# ike.preshared on hostA
#…
{ localidtype IP
    localid 10.4.0.1
    remoteidtype IP
    remoteid 10.4.0.2
    key keyinhexformat
    # The preshared key can also be represented in hex
# as in 0xf47cb0f432e14480951095f82b
# key "This is an ASCII Cqret phrAz, use str0ng p@ssword tekniques"
}
```

To generate the key in hex use this command

```
echo "mypassword" | od -t x1|head -1|tr -d ' '
```

The file

```
/etc/inet/ike/config
```

must be similar to this,even in this case use the ip of tunnel,not ip of main interface.

```
p1_xform
  { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha encr_alg 3des }
p2_pfs 2
{ label "test1-test2" local_addr 10.4.0.1 remote_addr 10.4.0.2 p1_xform { auth_method preshared oakley_group 5 auth_alg sha256 encr_alg aes } p2_pfs 5 }
```

Of course in hostB must be reverse 10.4.0.1 with 10.4.0.2
for both files.

Finally edit the file /etc/inet/ipsecinit.conf

```
{laddr 192.168.0.21 dir both} bypass {}
{laddr 10.4.0.1 raddr 10.4.0.2} ipsec {encr_algs aes encr_auth_algs sha256 sa shared}
```

Of course in hostB must be reverse 10.4.0.1 with 10.4.0.2
and 192.168.0.21 must be changed with host main ip of hostB

Now run the script on hostA

```
ifconfig ip.tun0 unplumb
ifconfig ip.tun0 plumb
ifconfig ip.tun0 10.4.0.1  10.4.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 tsrc 192.168.0.21 tdst 192.168.0.199 router up
for i in ike ipsec/policy;do svcadm refresh $i; done
```

Now run the script on hostB

```
ifconfig ip.tun0 unplumb
    ifconfig ip.tun0 plumb
    ifconfig ip.tun0 10.4.0.2  10.4.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 tsrc 192.168.0.199 tdst 192.168.0.21 router up
    for i in ike ipsec/policy;do svcadm refresh $i; done
```

And all works,test with ping and snoop.